# ADB pull command permission

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I do have a question in using ADB command in console. I know that user doesn't have a permission to access /system in shell without root permission as a default. But when I execute "adb pull /system/app /myApps" in a window console, not shell mode, it works properly. I mean, all apk files is copied into my desktop location without any problem.

Is it normal case? I got a root permission using exploit before. So, I'm not sure that 'pull' command is always able to copy system files with normal permission.

I'm thinking about to make ADB GUI application to be supportable for every android user. I need to know If it's possible without rooting! Please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it normal case?

For an emulator, maybe. For a rooted device, probably. For an ordinary device, no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal situation, because adb shell has the root permission. Usually we have root on the Emulator, but can't use su command from the Emulator Terminal. If you use adb shell you have su command (limited) from the computer stand of view, because adb shell is the owner, but not YOU!
Rooted device is not enough to use su command from the Emulator Terminal app.

If you want real su, read this stuff
http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Magic_Root_Access

After emulator exit, must redo the procedure again. I don't like it
I want to have real image file saved on the host computer for next reboot of the emulator. It makes me mad to repeat rooting and copying files to the system.
Google Staff don't like what I do, but I need different fonts in my system. That is!